# Expected value of the largest order statistic for $Uniform(\theta,2\theta)$

Tags: order-statistics, integral

I'm struggling to find when $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim Uniform(\theta,2\theta)$, how the expected value of the largest order statistic is $E[X_{(n)}]=\dfrac{2n+1}{n+1}\theta$. I can find that the density of the largest order statistic is $f(x_{(n)})=\dfrac{n}{\theta^n}(x_{(n)}-\theta)^{n-1}$ for $\theta \le x_{(n)} \le 2\theta$. But the expected value of $X_{(n)}$ doesn't seem to take such a nice form when I'm trying to do it.

Comment: Hint: If you define $Y = X_{(n)}/(2\theta)$, you should be able to recognize the density of $Y$ as a well-known distribution.

Comment: You can find this problem asked and answered, in various guises, in quite a few threads here on CV.  For instance, it's worked out at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130075.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465477 also answers your question. [Here's the site search that turned these up.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=uniform%20expect*%20max*%20%5bself-study%5d)  Please notice that upon recentering by $-\theta$ and scaling by $1/\theta$ your problem is reduced to the case of a uniform distribution on $(0,1),$

Comment: Thank you so much. I set $Y=X_{(n)}/\theta$ and it all simplified!